# Change top position based on width%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change my navigation bar's position from the top of the screen based on the screen width. I tried in CSS: `top: 10%`, but this is based on the height of the screen not the width.

Is there a way to get `top: .1 * width`?

Comment: What does 1*width mean?

Comment: post some code or show a jsfiddle.

Comment: you will need to use javascript to accomplish this

Comment: I'm going to follow this to see if there are newer answers :)

Comment: You need to use javascript to accomplish this as kennypu stated, but you need to be more clear with your question so people can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Quite often overlooked is that the vertical `margin` percentage properties of elements refer to their containing block's `width`, not just the horizontal ones.

That means that if you set something to `margin-top:10%;`, it will have a top margin equivalent to **10% of it's containing block's width**.

You can easily see that [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BRVq/). Try resizing the output panel vertically and horizontally, and note which resize direction makes the inner block move up and down.

You *can* use `vw` and `vh` and if your browser targets are allowing, I'd recommend that. But if you can't use them, you don't have to use Javascript right away. Too many people gun right away for Javascript when it opens up a whole new can of worms (like, what if the browser resizes?), especially when a bit of creative use of CSS can get you out of a sticky spot anyway.

Comment: Have been using margin percentages for a long time and I had no idea that's how they worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say there is no way to do so, but apparently in CSS3 since 2011 you have [vw/vh](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) that allow sizes to be relative to the viewport. For example:

```
img { height: 95vw; }
```

should give images a height that is 95% of the viewport width. Read more; apparently only IE9 supported it at the time of writing.

Comment: how would i invoke this once the screen hits x size, the same way I have a minimum width as #px and then the width as a %.

Comment: You will want to look at media queries for that, then.